# ¿Como listar procesos en Linux (Bash) con un tiempo de CPU mayor a 1 segundo?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Necesito listar en Linux los procesos que lleven mas de 1 segundo de CPU mediante el comando "ps"

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Qué has intentado? Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar un [mcve] de lo que hayas hecho hasta ahora. De esa manera tu pregunta será mejor recibida por la comunidad. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

Entiendo que te refieres a que lleven más de un segundo en ejecución, ¿correcto?

Si tu sistema tiene un "ps" actualizado, puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
ps -eo pid,etimes,etime,comm,user,tty | awk '{if ( $2>SEGUNDOS) print $0}'
```

En caso de un "ps" más antiguo, el siguiente comando te servirá:

```
ps -eo pid,etime,comm,user,tty | awk '{seconds_old=SEGUNDOS ; split($2,a,":",sep)  ; if(length(a) < 3)  b = (a[1] *60) + (a[2]) ; else  b=((a[1]*3600) + (a[2] *60) + (a[3])) ; if(b > seconds_old ) print $0}'
```

Cambia la palabra **SEGUNDOS** por 1, o los segundos por los que necesites filtrar.

Comment: Creo que el autor de la pregunta se refiere a tiempo de CPU y no a tiempo de ejecución. Aun así tu respuesta enseña cosas que no sabia.